# Java J2SE Code Compatibility in any OS

Tags: database, windows, java

I am in a confusion now. I am developing a java project in windows platform. but now, the problem is how can I get to know if my all codings (Java J2SE) will work in any OS? In my codings there are varies parts like serial port programming, smslib, RXTX lib, database connections (ODBC and JDBC). Can any one offer my some ideas or any solution for this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to be able to run across platforms, you must either not use platform specific libraries or find the right platform specific library for each system.  This is not a limitation of Java but the libraries you have used.  Note: you also need to ensure you can run on 32-bit and 64-bit JVMs as 32-bit DLLs will not work in a 64-bit JVM.

Comment: 64 and 32 bit is ok. I already configured that using my codings and configuring some internal configurations. I am completely worried about other plat forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work as long as you are not using any OS native APIs. Im afraid you might be doing so as you have mentioned your code uses things like serial port programmin, RXTX lib etc. If NOT then you are good to enjoy the Java 'write one and run anywhere' feature.

Comment: ya thats the point I am also worried, I am checking my coding in centOS, Now I am trouble shooting it. but what happen if the OS will get MAC or solaris or any?

Comment: @RakithaFernando Since you using native drivers, you need to test them all.  This is one reason Java is so popular because you don't need to do that with pure Java.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks for your comment buddy. but how every now I did this project with pure java which depend on RXTX,Comm library. The serial part programming part is the heart of this software. I am totally confused now. Its like headbang now.

Comment: @RakithaFernando There is no need to be confused. If you are using platform dependant software, you must test it on all the platforms you want to support including 32-bit and 64-bit.  For Windows you ideally want one for each version of windows as well.  It's a real pain, but a very simple problem.

Comment: Thanks for all the great suggestion. I am very honest to say that I put this question here because I really need the suggestions and help. So holding the question is very ugly thing to see and in this site there are many experts, but they are acting like when in the developing that they will not get any troubles. Same time they think that they are the only experts. Thank you very much.